# Issue with Selenium installation

Tags: selenium

I'm facing the following problem.

I'm trying to execute the code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.options import Options
```

And when I try to run it, the following error is returned:

> Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name 'Options' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.options'

I've checked other threads but none of them helped me.

I uninstalled selenium and installed again. Also, I double-checked to see if my file name wasn't selenium.py.

Can someone help me on that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like an installation issue.

I presume you mean to write this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

or

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
```